# Shell Scripts Renaming based on upload location

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, push

Ok So here's my question, I have a zip file that is currently pushing itself onto an SUV in two different locations

I now want to use arguments to rename the zip file base on where its going

for example if it is going to folder_1 I want to call it flyaway.zip

and if it is going to folder_2 I want it to be called gohome.zip

how do i do it, here is an example of its file path

and the zip i want to change is mega, i want to give it two different names based on where it is going

```
scp Mega.zip root@<the su>:/data/path/finalpath1
scp Mega.zip root@<the su>:/data/path/finalpath2
```

thank you for any help you can give

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to specifying a target directory, `scp` allows you to specify a target name, just as you would using `cp`:

```
scp Mega.zip root@<the su>:/data/path/finalpath1/flyaway.zip
scp Mega.zip root@<the su>:/data/path/finalpath2/gohome.zip
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i am very new to shell scripts